# ckeditor cdn not working when page loaded from file

Tags: cdn

I put the following (copied from the cdn website) in a file then opened it in FireFox A textarea is displayed rather than ckeditor. Is that expected behavior?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.7/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea name="editor1"></textarea>
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.7/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea name="editor1"></textarea>
  <script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
  </script>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Sorry I can't get that to display as code. I enclosed in backtics, also tried indenting by 4 spaces. No joy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [tutorial](http://brianmatovu.com/ckeditor-setup-configuration/) on how to setup and configure CKEditor in different environments, or get the demos' source code straight from [github](https://github.com/mtvbrianking/CKEditorTutorial)